# strcmp() return values in C

Tags: c, strcmp

I am learning about `strcmp()` in C. I understand that when two strings are equal, `strcmp` returns 0.

However, when the man pages state that `strcmp` returns less than 0 when the first string is less than the second string, is it referring to length, ASCII values, or something else?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In this sense, "less than" for strings means lexicographic (alphabetical) order.

So `cat` is less than `dog` because `cat` is alphabetically before `dog`.

Lexicographic order is, in some sense, an extension of alphabetical order to all ASCII (and UNICODE) characters.

Comment: From this answer someone could be led to believe that strcmp() knows about unicode.  That is not the case.

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant: For unicode, I was implicitly referring to the wide character version of `strcmp()`. But yes, I get your point.

Answer (score 8):

A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in the first string than in the second, and a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

Answer (score 6):

[C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 7.21.4:

> The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions
>   **memcmp**, **strcmp**, and **strncmp** is determined by the sign of
>   the difference between the values of the ﬁrst pair of characters (both
>   interpreted as **unsigned char**) that differ in the objects being
>   compared.

Note in particular that the result doesn't depend on the current locale; `LC_COLLATE` (see C99 7.11) affects `strcoll()` and `strxfrm()`, but not `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    int strcmp (const char * s1, const char * s2)
    {
        for(; *s1 == *s2; ++s1, ++s2)
           if(*s1 == 0)
               return 0;
        return *(unsigned char *)s1 < *(unsigned char *)s2 ? -1 : 1;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer would be considerably better if you could explain _why_ this answers the question.

Comment: it's also wrong answer, 1/-1 doesn't conform to C standard.
And you don't check before dereferencing.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 gcc is not returning -1 or 1. It returns (*s1 - *s2)

Answer (score -2):

Look out the following program, here I am returning the value depending upon the string you have typed. The function `strcmp` retrun value according to ASCII value of whole string considered totally.

For eg. `str1 = "aab"` and `str2 = "aaa"` will return 1 as aab > aaa.

```
int main()
{
    char str1[15], str2[15];
    int n;
    printf("Enter the str1 string: ");

    gets(str1);
    printf("Enter the str2 string : ");
    gets(str2);
    n = strcmp(str1, str2);
    printf("Value returned = %d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thank you for your answer. Please notice that this question was answered over two years ago and has a decent accepted answer. Also, your answer doesn't really answer the original question.