# How to make an alphabetical sort on double pointers in c?

Tags: c, string, pointers, alphabetical, double-pointer

```
qsort(Names, numberOfFriends, 50, strcmp);
```

I tried to make an  alphabetical sort on Names (wich is a double pointer). every string in the double pointer is dynamically allocated string, wich means every string have a different size. One of the parameters of the qsort function, is the size of the strings (it's actually a function that ment to 2d array, and not for double pointers with dynamically allocated strings).

How can i do an alphabetical sort on double pointers that have dynamically allocated strings?

Comment: Do you want to write a `qsort` function?

Comment: Yes, it will be helpful to write the function , but every code that get the jobe done - is great.

Comment: See partial answer below ... and I suggest if you want help with the sort routine you should post what you have or want modified -- otherwise your question is 'please write me a piece of code to do what I need' - it is better to ask 'how to convert this code from 2D array to ** pointer type?'

Comment: This is my first question in stack overflow -  For next time. Thank you sir for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer

The number of characters in the string is not so important - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518931/what-does-strcmp-return-if-two-similar-strings-are-of-different-lengths) - `strcmp` will compare the first `n` bytes of the arrays where the first `n-1` bytes are the same.

so to compare `Names[i]` and `Names[j]` you should be able to use

```
differentce=strcmp(Names[i], Names[j]);
```

provided that `Names` is declared as `char ** Names`.

If you want more help with how to do this I suggest you put more code in your question.