# Why can't I use "==" in this specific instance?

Tags: c

Why can't I use the == operator to compare two string
variables in C? Example:

```
char name1[] = "John";
char name2[] = "John";
if (name1==name2)
printf("Same!");
```

Comment: Because that's comparing addresses, not contents. You have to use `strcmp()` to compare strings.

Comment: Because the `string` type doesn't exist in C. A string of character is a derived type made using an array of `char` conventionally ended with a null. To compare two arrays you must use functions comparing element by element. A specialized function exist in C to check strings, `strcmp()`, that compare the two characters array element by element and stops when a difference is encountered or a null character is found. It returns -1, 0 or 1 respectively if string1 is less than, equal or greater then  string2.

Comment: This should have been explained in whatever textbook or tutorial you used to learn C.

Comment: Would you want the characters of `name1` to change if somebody modified characters of your `name2`? Because that's what would happen if they were equal.

Comment: Under most circumstances, array expressions "decay" to pointers to their first element - what you've written is equivalent to `if ( &name1[0] == &name2[0] )`, which will never be true.  There *is* a reason for that behavior, but it's too long to fit in a comment.  Similarly, you can't use `=` to assign an entire array (such as `name1 = "foo"`).  You have to use the `strcmp` library function to compare strings (`if ( strcmp(name1, name2) == 0 )`), and you have to use functions like `strcpy` to assign strings (`strcpy( name1, "foo" );`).

Comment: @Frankie_C `strcmp()` returns any positive or negative non-zero value if strings are not equal.

Comment: @dimich Thanks for the clarification. I simplified the the concept, but forget to mention my older answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518931/what-does-strcmp-return-if-two-similar-strings-are-of-different-lengths/36519262#36519262, which is much more detailed.